# Axios object as params not readable by backend

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a problem with my axios query:

```
apiClient.get('http://localhost:8080/api/internalLocations/search', {
      params: {
        locationTypeCode: 'BIN_LOCATION',
        offset: '0',
        max: '5',
        parentLocation: {
          id: `${this.props.currentLocation}`,
        },
      },
    })
```

The query needs to be typeof `?[...]offset=5&parentLocation.id=xyz`, but now it is like this: `&offset=0&max=5&parentLocation={"id":"[object Object]"}` and the backend doesn't know how to handle that.
Is there any possibility to make it `parentLocation.id=xyz`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it should work

```
apiClient.get('http://localhost:8080/api/internalLocations/search', {
      params: {
        locationTypeCode: 'BIN_LOCATION',
        offset: '0',
        max: '5',
        'parentLocation.id': `${this.props.currentLocation}`,
      },
    })
```